# Inject html into UIWebVeiw

Tags: javascript, dom, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that I am trying to inject some html code into. I have a template file that I load first, then I want to alter the content of elements by their ID.

Here is my code, in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`:

```
    NSString *injectDetails = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = \"%@\";", searchResult.details];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:injectDetails];
```

I have tried it by escaping the quotes and that didn't work either:

```
    NSString *injectDetails = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = \"%@\";", [searchResult.details stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""]];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:injectDetails];
```

I cab  inject plain text, and it works. The html that doesn't work is a lengthy string that I had originally simply loaded using `[webView loadHTMLString:aDescription baseURL:NULL];` That worked fine.

What do I need to do make this work with html?

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem when trying to add style to document's head. So I just escaped all double quotas with \\" (which looks like \" in script). See code below:

```
NSString *js = @" <style type=\\\"text/css\\\"> * { -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; } </style> ";
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML+\"%@\"",js]];
```

Answer (score -1):

try the following line of code to make this happens.

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *HTMLData = @"Hello this is a test<img src="sample.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" />";

[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];
```

Line 1
 This will get the path to the main bundle root folder.

Line 2
We need the slashes to be double slashed to work correctly in the UIWebView, so we are searching for all instances of “/” and replacing it with “//”

Line 3
Same deal as above but we are searching for a space and replacing it with the HTML equivalent of %20

Line 4
This is putting some sample data together for out UIWebView, you will see that we have set the images source to just our “sample.jpg” file as it is sitting in the root folder, if it was in a folder called “images” we would need to set the source to “images//sample.jpg”. Remember the double slashing!

Line 5
This is pretty much the same as my example in the tutorial although we are setting the baseURL to the root of our application bundle, this allows us to reference everything relatively instead of absolute paths.

Using the above you can do this.. let me know if any issue occurs..

Comment: If you're answering my question, I don't see the connection.

Comment: do you want to show HTML in UIWebView - please let me know if i am going in wrong direction.

Comment: I want to solve the specific problem of injecting html into an exiting uiview that already has html in it. This is a dom and javascript related question.